# in pyplot hist2D with customized colorbar mark bins outside colorbar range

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I'm plotting a weighted 2D histogram with one value assigned to each bin. Here's a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter

plot_field, axis_field = plotter.subplots()



x = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
y = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]
w = [2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]


minimum = 1
bins = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
histo = plotter.hist2d(x, y, bins=bins, weights=w)

plotter.colorbar(histo[3], extend='min')
plotter.clim(minimum, max(w))
plotter.show()
```

Restricting the range of the colorbar works fine. However, I want to the bins with weight below the minimum to be marked in some way. Either colored differently or indicated in some other way.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you include your import statements in your MWE so we can run it?

Comment: added imports... sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own [`colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-listed-colormaps) for example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap


plot_field, axis_field = plotter.subplots()

viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 256)
newcolors = viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
pink = np.array([248/256, 24/256, 148/256, 1])
newcolors[0, :] = pink
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)

x = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
y = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]
w = [2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]

minimum = 1
bins = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
_, _, _, mesh = plotter.hist2d(
    x, y, bins=bins, weights=w, cmap=newcmp, vmin=minimum, vmax=max(w)
)

plotter.colorbar(mesh, extend='min')
plotter.show()
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm, very nice and many thanks